# Operator overloading confusion in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

While using cppinsights to see how C++ sees lambda expression. The following part confused me.

```
// C++17
int main(){
   int x = 10;
   auto ff = [](int a) constexpr { return 1.2; };
}
```

to this

```
int main()
{
  int x = 10;
    
  class __lambda_3_14
  {
    public: 
    inline /*constexpr */ double operator()(int a) const
    {
      return 1.2;
    }
    
    using retType_3_14 = double (*)(int);
    inline /*constexpr */ operator retType_3_14 () const noexcept
    {
      return __invoke;
    };
    
    private: 
    static inline double __invoke(int a)
    {
      return 1.2;
    }
    
    
    public:
    // /*constexpr */ __lambda_3_14() = default;
    
  };
  
  __lambda_3_14 ff = __lambda_3_14{};
}
```

[link to the demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4o61rPMxM)

What does this line mean `inline /*constexpr */ operator retType_3_14 () const noexcept` especially `operator retType_3_14 ()` . What operator is being overloaded?

Comment: The line above declares `retType_3_14` as an alias to a function pointer. The operator below is for converting the lambda to a function pointer.

Comment: I'm still a noob. How can I re-write the above without the alias `retType_3_14`?

Comment: Why would you want to? As the name of the site implies, cppinsights is for insight, not a manual for writing code. The point of lambdas is that this is all taken care of for you. To answer the question, just take the thing that `ret_3_14` is meant to represent, and plug it in place ret_3_14`.

Comment: Lambda can be implicitly converted to function pointer (if it doesn't capture anything). This `inline /*constexpr */ operator retType_3_14 ()` is just expresses this implicit conversion. Demo: https://cppinsights.io/s/cfbbb699

Comment: @sweenish I'm just learning, was curious what that line does. I'm still confused about it. There's no return type mentioned and how do I invoke that function so, I can get a clear idea of what's happening.

Comment: A lambda is highly concentrated syntactic sugar and/or fructose.

Comment: @Yelp This is common to all conversion operators: they are written as `operator typename()`, e.g. `operator bool() { ... }` to allow conversion of the type too type `bool` via `static_cast`; Example: `struct BoolHolder { bool m_val; operator bool() { return m_val; }} ... BoolHolder b; b.m_val = true; bool value = static_cast<bool>(b);`

Comment: @fabian Thank you so much!!!!! Now I understand it. Consider posting it as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Anyone know what the `_3_14` _name_ represents?  Oh, it's probably the line number  + character offset, thus guaranteeing uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) with an empty capture list defines a `ClosureType` with the following member function

```
ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()
```

which is a conversion to a function pointer `ret(*)(params)`, where `ret` and `params` are the return type and arguments of `ClosureType::operator()`.

Your lambda `ff` takes an `int` and returns a `double`, so it's convertible to a function pointer `double(*)(int)`, which is aliased by the typedef `retType_3_14`. The function pointer it returns is just pointer to a private member function of the lambda closure type that duplicates the functionality of `operator()`.

Comment: I find myself very surprised that it duplicates the functionality rather than just using `operator()`, but maybe it only does that for small methods? Oh, there's `const` issues.  Still, `operator()` could have been implemented in terms of `__invoke`

Comment: @MooingDuck Sure, an implementation could do call `__invoke` from `operator()` if it wanted I guess. It seems odd to have a function call instead of just returning `1.2`. but it's up to the implementation really.

Comment: Sure in this case it's moot, but in my codebase at work, I just saw a 200 line lambda so...

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh yeah, a compiler might do fairly different things internally, depending on the lambda itself. Though, a 200 line lambda sounds like an issue that you might want to tackle first :)

Comment: I about tackled my teammate is what I did :D